# Scaffolding a database in SSMS within Visual Studio to deploy on Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, visual-studio, azure-deployment, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I have created a database in Azure and connected it in SSMS, but when I try to scaffold it in Visual Studio I always get the same error which says:

> login failed for 'user'.

Any tips on how I can successfully scaffold it?.

I tried disconnecting and reconnecting it again, and I also changed my login details and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***When I tried to reproduce your requirement in my environment, I got the same error*** `login failed for user "username"`.

[image]

[image]

**Steps to fix the issue:**

- Go to your SQL Server in Azure Portal and Reset its Password.

[image]

[image]

- Open SSMS and enter your new credentials along with the Server name. Click on options=> Connection Properties=>Select **your database** in `Connect to data base` instead of **default**.

[image]

- In Visual Studio, Go to `Tools=>Connect to database`, check if the Test connection is Successful or not.

[image]

Finally, Run the below given **Scaffolding command** in `Package Manager` console in `Visual Studio`.

```cs
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=tcp:<yourservername>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<your_database_name>;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<User_name>;Password=<your_newly_created_password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

[image]

**Model classes has been generated as shown below:**

[image]